# Combine/merge left & right video files

Tags: linux, video-conversion, 3d-multimedia

How can I join the two parts of a stereoscopic movie to get a side-by-side one?

I can expand the left file, that way all I'll need is to paste the second one on top of it, with something like this:

```
mencoder left-file.mkv -o side-by-side.avi -oac copy -ovc lavc -of avi -vf scale=1280:720,expand=-1280:0:0:0 -sws 3 -lavcopts vbitrate=16000
```

Any idea which tool should I use on a Linux system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - I've put a handy wrapper script around this and started a project at SourceForge. I've called it *videomerge3d*

http://videomerge3d.sourceforge.net/

---

Try GStreamer

I'm sure someone will put a nice wrapper on this functionality soon... in the meantime you can use the command line gst-launch program:

Replace my MVI_0735L.MOV and MVI_0735R.MOV with your files and out.avi with whatever you want it to be saved as.

To play movies ( reduced to (640x2)x320 views - can't play 2560x720 as my screen is too narrow ), non-linux might need to modify the 'xvimagesink' to something else.

```
gst-launch filesrc location=MVI_0736L.MOV ! decodebin2 name=LeftVid ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=360 ! videobox border-alpha=0 right=-640 ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink filesrc location=MVI_0735R.MOV ! decodebin2 name=RightVid ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=360 ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-640 ! mix. LeftVid. ! audioconvert ! audiopanorama panorama=-1.00 ! adder name=addaudio ! queue ! autoaudiosink  RightVid. ! audioconvert ! audiopanorama panorama=1.00 ! queue ! addaudio.
```

To combine 720P movies:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=MVI_0735L.MOV ! decodebin name=Left ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1280, height=720 ! videobox border-alpha=0 right=-1280 ! queue ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! avimux name=avmux ! queue ! progressreport name="Encoding Progress" ! filesink location=out.avi filesrc location=MVI_0735R.MOV ! decodebin name=Right ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1280, height=720 ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-1280 ! queue ! mix.   Left. ! audioconvert ! audiopanorama panorama=-1.00 ! adder name=addaudio ! faac ! queue ! avmux.  Right. ! audioconvert ! audiopanorama panorama=1.00 ! queue ! addaudio.
```

Here's a more readable version ( using \ to join the lines):

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=MVI_0735L.MOV ! decodebin2 name=Left \
                filesrc location=MVI_0735R.MOV ! decodebin2 name=Right \
 Left. ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1280, height=720 ! videobox border-alpha=0 right=-1280 ! queue ! mix. \
 Right. ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1280, height=720 ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-1280 ! queue ! mix.  \
 Left. ! decodebin2 ! audioconvert ! audiopanorama panorama=-1.00 ! queue ! addaudio. \
 Right. ! decodebin2 ! audioconvert ! audiopanorama panorama=1.00 ! queue ! addaudio. \
 adder name=addaudio ! faac ! avmux.  \
 videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! \
 avimux name=avmux ! progressreport name="Encoding Progress" ! filesink location=out.avi
```

- for other video compression replace x264enc with jpegenc etc.
- for other audio compression replace faac with lame  or just remove it alogether.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, [JJones](http://superuser.com/users/72280/jjones)! I have GStreawer on my system, but I never knew it is capable of doing this...